# Monotone function related

Tags: real-analysis

I have learned that a monotone function will only have a discontinuity of first kind. My doubt is the function 1/x is monotone function but the limit of function as it approaches zero is infinity. Then it contradicts my first statement. Can someone give me an explanation to this doubt of mine?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can talk about discontinuities, you have to define what the domain of the function is. For$f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, the function is actually continuous. I don't know what level of math you are at regarding continuity, but any sequence $(x_n)$ in $(0,\infty)$ that converges to $x \in (0,\infty)$, we have the image of that sequence converging to $\frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$. You may ask, "what about at $x=0$?" Well $0 \not \in (0,\infty)$, so my response is "don't worry about it."

I'm assuming a jump discontinuity is a discontinuity of the first kind. I'm fairly certainly that $f$ does not have a jump continuity. It is in fact not a discontinuity but an asymptote.